# Matplotlib - computing screen coordinates for function calls

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just started to explore matplotlib and related documentation. There is one thing which I am still not clear about even after going through the documentation. Below are some statements I copied from random examples. Most of the functions take arguments related to screen positions, for example: margin, padding, text placement/position etc. Most of the arguments are not the x,y arguments (numpy array) of the plot/bar etc, but screen positions. For instance when I see an example program on the documentation using margin = 0.2, how was this value arrived at? Was it based on trial and error? Same goes for padding, figtext,etc. I do not want to do this trial and error approach for each of these kind of functions and see how my figure looks.
Is there any way to compute these values? Or is there any recommended standard which I can use to form my imagination when I call such functions.

```
plt.margins(0.2)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
plt.figtext(0.9, 0.05, '$x$')
ax.text(2, 6, r'an equation: $E=mc^2$', fontsize=15)
ax.annotate('annotate', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(3, 4), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally the documentation would state which coordiante systems is used for the respective numeric values. I think it does so in most cases.

- `plt.margins(0.2)`: use 20% margin on both sides of the data towards the axes boundary.
- `fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)`: Start the top subplot at 85% of the figure height.
- `plt.figtext(0.9, 0.05, '$x$')`: Annotate the point 90% and 5% away from the lower left corner of the figure.
- `ax.text(2, 6, "text")`, `ax.annotate('annotate', xy=(2,6))`: Annotate the point `(2,6)` in data units.

So the first three use relative numbers, the last uses data coordinates.